# Input value into new field based on value in OID field

Tags: python, arcpy

I need to input PofC in the PNT_TYP field (created in the script below) in my feature class (assigned to the variable verts) the odd OID values will have PofC input in PNT_TYP and the even with PofT. I am not sure how to do this. I have tried a number of things but this code does not seem to be working. If I have to run it in ArcMap then this will not work as I am trying to make it part of a larger script? if that is the case how do I do this so that I can run it from a script? I am not getting an error message, it just prints out script completed at the end like the script says to but the PNT_TYP field is blank in the feature class (as this script converts it to a lyr file) and I do not see any lyr file. I have never used one so I do not know if it would show in the catalogue or not. I have updated this to include the whole script but it is just the end where I need that one column to be updated with the two values based on the OID value that I am not sure if it is working as I see nothing to indicate it is.

```
# imports
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
gdb = raw_input("please input the path of the GDB you are working with. >> ")
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
in_fc = raw_input("Please input the fc that requires utm coordinates. >> ").upper().strip()
out_fc = raw_input("Please enter the name of the new start and end point feature class. eg) RoadNo_amdNo_pnts >> ").upper().strip()

###################################################################################################

arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(in_fc, out_fc, "BOTH_ENDS") #creating point fc from line fc
# coord = arcpy.AddField_management ("verts", "PNT_TYP","TEXT", "","",25)
# code using modulus possibly to determine PofC and PofT.

#################################################################################

arcpy.AddXY_management(out_fc) #creating points for each vertex

#################################################################################

verts = raw_input("What do you want to call your final feature class? Eg. R18564_amd5_UTM >> ")
y_field = 'POINT_Y' #column of y values
x_field = 'POINT_X' #column of x values
input_format = 'SHAPE'
output_format = 'UTM'

arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(out_fc, verts, x_field, y_field, input_format, output_format)#takes out_fc (from vertices tool) and writes out to verts

coord = arcpy.AddField_management (verts, "Coords","TEXT", "","",25)
expression = '!UTM!.split(" ")[1] + ", " + !UTM!.split(" ")[2]'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(verts, "Coords", expression, "PYTHON_9.3")

in_fld = arcpy.AddField_management (verts, "PNT_TYP", "TEXT", "","",25)

###################################################################

in_feature = os.path.join(gdb, verts)

feat_lyr = raw_input("What would you like to call the feature layer? >> "

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (verts, feat_lyr)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (feat_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", 'MOD("OID", 2) = 0')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feat_lyr, "PNT_TYP", '!PNT_TYP! = "PofT"', "PYTHON_9.3")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (feat_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", 'MOD("OID", 2) > 0')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feat_lyr, "PNT_TYP", '!PNT_TYP! = "PofC"', "PYTHON_9.3")

print ("script complete.")
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or what do you mean by not working?

Comment: No I did not get any errors at all. the script runs and then prints script complete but nothing is populated in the PNT_TYP column.

Comment: You could solve this using only da.UpdateCursor. Or do you need the layer for something else? What is `PofT`, a field?

Comment: The PofT is the point of terminus and the PofC is the Point of Commencement. They indicate where my road lines start and end and are used in maps I create which are attached to permit approvals. I need them to be in a field so that I can label them PofC or PofT on my map. Otherwise I have to manually create the labels and there can be many of these points sometimes.

Comment: I also need the UTM coordinates for all the points which are done earlier in the script, just not shown here. I had already posted a question on that but eventually found out where I was wrong and posted the answer that I found. I will update my code above to include that part too.

Comment: That can be done at the same time with the updatecursor using shape@xy token

Comment: Ok, thanks I will look at that option. I am just figuring out all this Python and ArcPy stuff as I go here as that is how I learn best. I will post an answer when I figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Try using da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy

gdb = r'C:\data.gdb'
verts = 'pointfc'

in_feature = os.path.join(gdb, verts)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_feature, ["OID@", "PNT_TYP"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] % 2 == 0:
            row[1] = 'PofT'
        else:
            row[1] = 'PofC'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

And if you also want to populate two fields with the x, y coordinates of your points, change "X" and "Y" to the names of your fields:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_feature, ["OID@", "PNT_TYP", "X", "Y", "SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] % 2 == 0:
            row[1] = 'PofT'
        else:
            row[1] = 'PofC'
        row[2], row[3] = row[4]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. This is what my final script looks like

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
gdb = raw_input("please input the path of the GDB you are working with. >> ")
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
in_fc = raw_input("Please input the fc name that requires utm coordinates. >> ").upper().strip()
xy_fc = "{}_XY".format(in_fc)

##########################################################################################

arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(in_fc, xy_fc, "BOTH_ENDS") #creating vertex points fc 
arcpy.AddXY_management(xy_fc) #adding xy coords for each vertex

##########################################################################################

utm_fc = "{}_UTM".format(in_fc)
y_field = 'POINT_Y' #column of y values
x_field = 'POINT_X' #column of x values
input_format = 'SHAPE'
output_format = 'UTM'

arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(xy_fc, utm_fc, x_field, y_field, input_format, output_format)#takes out_fc (from vertices tool) and writes out to utm_fc
in_fld = arcpy.AddField_management (utm_fc, "PNT_TYP", "TEXT", "","",25)

in_feature = os.path.join(gdb, utm_fc)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_feature, ["OID", "PNT_TYP"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] %2 == 0:
            row[1] = 'PofT'
        else:
            row[1] = 'PofC'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```